# How to use CSS/SVG for iOS7 native UI

Tags: ios, css, ios7, svg

I am working on an iOS7 version of an existing web app. Most of the icons used in the web app are defined in CSS:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII...
```

Previously, I have requested PNG copies of the relevant icons from the designer, but as the application grows, that is getting cumbersome. I am looking for one of two solutions:

- A way to render the SVG as UI in iOS, instead of PNG based UIImages.
- A tool (browser extension?) to automatically extract images (for a given screen size) as PNG or similar.

I have briefly tried [Pixate](http://pixate.github.io/), but I couldn't find any documentation for my particular use case, and ran in to several quirks.